# Rasa NLU , intent = null for single word sentences

Tags: spacy, rasa-nlu

I'm using Rasa NLU tu identify intents. After setting some intents and entities I got an intent with confidence over 0.45 even if the word has nothing to do.

Is there a way to show intent = null for single word questions?

My current pipeline is : pretrained_embeddings_spacy

regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding an intent with the name "null" and add some single tokens as training data?

Comment: Thanks! , will try to do that, actually im doing this condition in backend